# How to deploy tomcat applications (or virtual hosts) on demand?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, virtualhost, startup, server.xml

I've a tomcat server running on a debian machine. There are a lot of virtual hosts on my tomcat server & each host contains a CMS application.
Since tomcat deploys all applications at start up, it has a too long start up time & since I need to restart my server periodically, this long startup time become a real pain for me.
I don't want to use all of these hosts immediately after starting tomcat, so I'm seeking for a way to avoid auto-deploy all applications at start up, instead I need to tell tomcat deploy each application (e.g. each CMS on every virtual host) upon first access. I guess it must be possible with correct configuration in tomcat startup scripts or server.xml or other configuration files.
Any idea?

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment

Comment: this is not the answer of my question because if you set `deployOnStartup` to false, then you have to deploy each application manually!